# Python : Check if after a pattern match N chacaters are present

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I want to check if there are more than 50 characters present after a pattern match in the text file. I thought I could use a regex, but how can I do that?
for example, My text file looks like this...

Case1:

```
aaa addfd
bbbfd fd fdg
ccddff LLLL
```

Case2:

```
aaa addfd
bbbfd fd fdg
ccddff LLLL
asa dfg
```

I want to check if anything exists after the string "LLLL".

Comment: any example? any attempts?

Comment: Have you tried adding `.{50}` to the end of the pattern?

Comment: Please include at least one sample input and output cases to help people understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
my_regex_object = re.compile(r'(whatever_you_want_here)(.{51,})')
```

You said more than 50, so I used {51,} which will only match 51 or more instances of the wildcard character.  If you want 50 or more, then just use {50,}